# How to create a user login page and shopkeeper login page on parse server?

Tags: java, android

i already created a user login page using parseserver.

```
public class loginactivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener,View.OnKeyListener{
EditText username;
EditText password;
TextView signuptextview;
ImageView logo;
ConstraintLayout layout;
```

---

this the code for my login page

```
@override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        loginbutton(v);      `//to make the keypad go down
}
    return false;
}
@override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view.getId()== R.id.signupTextView){
        Intent intent= new Intent(loginactivity.this,MainActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);                                           // to switch between login and signup page
    }else if (view.getId()== R.id.logo || view.getId()== R.id.layout){
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager= (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),0);
    }
}`@override` public void loginbutton(View view) {
    if (username.getText().toString().matches("")  || password.getText().toString().matches("")) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "username and password required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {

        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString(), new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (user != null) {
                 Intent mainintent = new Intent(loginactivity.this, mainpage_activity.class);
                 startActivity(mainintent);  // login code
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(loginactivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}`
```

---

now i want to create a shopkeeper login page within this project in new activity.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and tell us what you have tried so far to solve your problem (create a shopkeeper login page), so we have a basis to work with you toward your solution.

Comment: i created a class on the parseserver manually and tried to access that class from new activity. I want to use that class like Parseuser to add detalis of signup for shopkeeper. My issue is how can i access that class .